# Not able to render the weather[0].main property from the openWeatherMap Api, it gives an error of undefine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, openweathermap

I am using React Hooks and geolocation to get the longitude and latitude for getting the weather data from OpenWeatherMap, right now I can render the weatherData.name property but the `weatherData.weather[0].main` gives:

> TypeError of undefined.

React code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const API_KEY = 'e683d9ae190fbf9ecf7a63c274ee7146';

function SearchWeather() {
    
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState({})

    function getLonLat(){
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                const lon = position.coords.longitude;
                const lat = position.coords.latitude;
                fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${API_KEY}`)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(result => {

                        setWeatherData(result)
                        
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            })
        
}
}

useEffect(() => getLonLat())

return (
    <div>
        <h1>{weatherData.name}</h1>
        <h1>{weatherData.weather[0].main}</h1>
    </div>   
)  
}
export default SearchWeather;
```

Error message

```
TypeError: weatherData.weather is undefined
SearchWeather
H:/React App/weather-app/w-app/src/components/SearchWeather.js:32

  29 | return (
  30 |     <div>
  31 |         <h1>{weatherData.name}</h1>
> 32 |         <h1>{weatherData.weather[0].main}</h1>
  33 |     </div>   
  34 | )  
  35 | }
```

OpenWeatherMap result data

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 91.81,
    "lat": 26.14
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 701,
      "main": "Mist",
      "description": "mist",
      "icon": "50d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 307.15,
    "feels_like": 313.68,
    "temp_min": 307.15,
    "temp_max": 307.15,
    "pressure": 1004,
    "humidity": 71
  },
  "visibility": 5000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 2.7,
    "deg": 274
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 75
  },
  "dt": 1598513732,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 9117,
    "country": "IN",
    "sunrise": 1598484652,
    "sunset": 1598530686
  },
  "timezone": 19800,
  "id": 1272508,
  "name": "Dispur",
  "cod": 200
}
```

What am I missing is there something wrong with accessing the value?

Comment: Try `weatherData.weather && weatherData.weather[0].main`. because at runtime the values are still loading.

Comment: Yes got it Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `null` or `undefined` check before using that. The API returns later with the result, so initially you have an empty object as `{}` based on your `useState({})`.

Solution could be:

```
<h1>
  {
     weatherData &&
     weatherData.weather &&
     weatherData.weather[0] &&
     weatherData.weather[0].main
  }
</h1>
```

Or even shorter as `weatherData.weather && weatherData.weather[0].main`.